# How to extracct all sentences that include at least one word formatted with a particular style with VBA word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Say I have the following text in word.

```
Lorem ipsum RED sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Ut enim BLUE ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.

Some line.

Another Line here.
```

The words RED and BLUE are formatted in the style "COLOR". I would like to extract these two sentences using VBA.

I tried to modify a working routine by making it search for style instead of text, but I was not able to make it work.

My code:

```
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
''|                                                                  |
''|                                                                  |
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
' The purpose of this is to extract sentences that contain a certain
' style
Sub A1ExtractCopy_STYLE()

' the text to extract and or highlight
Dim myStyle As String: myStyle = "Idioms"

' the current document
    Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = ActiveDocument.Range
' the new document
    Dim NewDocument As Document: Set NewDocument = Documents.Add
    Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = NewDocument.Range

    With r1
        .Find.Format = True
        .FormattedText.Style = myStyle
        Do While .Find.Execute
            r1.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
            r2.Characters.Last.FormattedText = r1.FormattedText
            r2.InsertParagraphAfter
            r1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
    Set r1 = Nothing

 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly find `Style`. Please, try changing the existing loop in:

```
  'your existing code
  With r1.Find
    .Style = myStyle 
    Do While .Execute
       r1.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
       r2.Characters.Last.FormattedText = r1.FormattedText
       r2.InsertParagraphAfter
       r1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
  'your existing code
```